# Openstack cloud (identity service, nova service and swift service) vs Java application

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-horizon

I want to build a Java application to access the OpenStack services like the Identity Service (username, password, secret key, etc), Nova service (create and remove virtual machines, etc) and Swift service (upload and download files, etc).

I set up OpenStack Cloud in three machines and downloaded the Java SDK files to access the cloud resources from this link https://github.com/woorea/openstack-java-sdk

I need simple Java code to access the usernames that have registered in the cloud.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to tidy up the language and formatting in your post. It would help if you explained what you have tried already for accessing usernames, what documentation you have consulted, and what exact problem you are having.

Comment: Hi i have to implement the system as per attached  document http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~pclee/www/pubs/securecomm10.pdf .So i mplemented cloud part using openstack with the help of the documentation http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/ . And i logged into the cloud using the specific URL.But My exact problem is to "how to login to the cloud using my java application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project on github ([CloudServiceDeployer](https://github.com/dtrihinas/CloudServiceDeployer)) handling almost what you were asking for.

Take a more closer view to the classes below

- [OpenstackConnector.java](https://github.com/dtrihinas/CloudServiceDeployer/blob/master/CloudServiceDeployer/src/main/java/cy/ac/ucy/linc/cloudDeployer/connectors/openstack/OpenstackConnector.java)
- [Deployer.java](https://github.com/dtrihinas/CloudServiceDeployer/blob/master/CloudServiceDeployer/src/main/java/cy/ac/ucy/linc/cloudDeployer/deployment/Deployer.java)

Comment: I don not have the jars to provide them. You have to build the project by your own. It is a maven project, so maven will handle any other dependencies you might need during the compile / build process.

Answer (score 0):

There is java SDK(aka jcloud) is available to access the openstack functionality.

wiki link : https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OpenStack-SDK-Java

Comment: can you give an example code  to access cloud information(Any simple one.Eg:login section to openstack cloud)