# Use of jClouds or openstack4j with OpenStack

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds

I must create a java application to interface with an openstack (loggin, create and manage istances and images) system but I'm finding more problem ane had some question:
1) between jClouds and openstack4j who is better?
2) i try to use both but with 4j i can't find some exaustive example and with jclouds i have great problem to login with keystone error :

```
 *server error:    [method=org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.public abstract org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.Access org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.PasswordCredentials)[xxx, PasswordCredentials{username=xxx, password=xxx}], request=POST http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1]*
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: PS. i try to login with 4j too, but i have another error that timed out...how can i fix it?

Comment: See my answer here: [Openstack cloud (identity service, nova service and swift service) vs Java application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28985001/2279200), it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into both jcloud and openstack4j a while ago, and decided to go with Openstack4J. Although both SDKs are in development, I think that jcloud is raw, and that openstack4j is better for developing Openstack applications.

Answer (score 0):

Francesco:
     For your first question,I think both of them are fine for me, they all have most fundamental functions.Howerver, Jclouds doesn't provide us Ceilometer API.What a pity.
     As for your second question abt identification,here is a sample code via openstack4j:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
                       .endpoint("http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0")
                       .credentials("admin","sample")
                       .tenantName("admin")
                       .authenticate();
```

also,you can get more information form  http://www.openstack4j.com/learn/compute/

Hope my answer can help you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using openstack4j in production and i find it very useful, the best part is the community is vibrant and with frequent releases its getting more mature day by day.

Answer (score 0):

I tried jclouds but then switched to openstack4j as richer functionality.

But unfortunately at the present time openstack4j project seems no longer evolving. New contributions are not merged since march 2018. So you will not be able to work with OpenStack releases starting from Queens because all projects operations will fail.