# Connection timeout with openstack4j compute query

Tags: java, cloud, glassfish, openstack, openstack4j

I'm trying out openstack4j, and I've run into a problem I don't know what could be causing.

Authentication to the cloud went smoothly:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
.endpoint("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyyy/v2.0")
.credentials(username,password)
.tenantName("admin")
.perspective(Facing.PUBLIC)
.authenticate();
```

However, once os is instanciated, I try running the following line:

```
List<? extends Flavor> flavors = os.compute().flavors().list();
```

And I get an ConnectionException{message=java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect, status=0}

What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "main" ConnectionException{message=java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect, status=0}
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:58)
    at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:33)
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.internal.HttpExecutor.execute(HttpExecutor.java:51)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:178)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.BaseOpenStackService$Invocation.execute(BaseOpenStackService.java:172)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.compute.internal.FlavorServiceImpl.list(FlavorServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.mycompany.app.my_app.OpenStackCom.authOpenStack(OpenStackCom.java:127)
    at com.mycompany.app.my_app.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:224)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:656)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:653)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:653)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:388)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpCommand.execute(HttpCommand.java:86)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invokeRequest(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:65)
at org.openstack4j.connectors.jersey2.HttpExecutorServiceImpl.invoke(HttpExecutorServiceImpl.java:56)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:321)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. You can try an alternative of openstack4j named JClouds, personally I find it more easy to use. You can also take a look on my awnser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28985001/2279200). I am giving some links about a simple java application that can help start with JClouds.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I haven't yet figured out why this is happening, however I have found that if I use another connector then the error gets resolved. I'm now using resteasy and it's proven very efficient.